# How to create two objects from one object if fields are not same in object?

Tags: javascript

I have below array of objects and I have to create a new array of objects based on the below conditions

1. if id is not empty and registration id is empty push this object into the result array.
2. if registration id is not empty and id is empty then assign registration id to id and push this object into the result array.
3. if id is not empty and registration id is not empty then

   a.check id and registration id are the same then assign registration id to id push this object into the result array.

   b. id and registration id are not same create two object .one with "id": 1 and another one with
   assign registration id to id("id": 100)

```js
var userData =[{
"id": 1,
"name": "abcd",
"place":"xyz",
"registrationid": 100


}];

var result = [];

userData.forEach( (element) => {
   if(element.id !="" && element.registrationid ==""){
        console.log("1");
        result.push(element);
        
   } else if(element.registrationid !="" && element.id ==""){
        console.log("2");
        element.id  = element.registrationid;
        result.push(element);
        
   } else if(element.registrationid !="" && element.id !=""){
             console.log("3");
          if(element.id  == element.registrationid){
          console.log("4");
            element.id  = element.registrationid;
              result.push(element);
            
        }else if(element.id  != element.registrationid){
          console.log("5");
          result.push(element)
          element.id  = element.registrationid;
            result.push(element)
        }
        
   }
});

console.log(result)
```

Expected output
result array should return

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"name": "abcd",
"place":"xyz",
"registrationid": 100
},
{
"id": 100,
"name": "abcd",
"place":"xyz",
"registrationid": 100
},

];
```

Gone through this but could not get any idea please help me out guys

Comment: Why do you need to assign registration ID to ID in 3a.? You should create a copy in 3b.: `result.push({ ...element})`.

Comment: @jabaa that's the requirement means userid is and registration are same we will consider registration id

Comment: If they are the same, why do you need to assign? They already are the same. `if (a === b) a = b;` doesn't make sense.

Comment: An observation in point 3.a is not redundant because if record id is equal to id it is not necessary to assign value from one to another because they are the same

Comment: Another detail. When formulating questions it is better that the conditions are formulated positively. The reason is that I read somewhere that people find it more difficult to understand questions formulated in the negative. For example instead of `if id is not empty and registration...` use `if id has value and ...`, sorry for the offtopic

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy in step 3b:

```js
var userData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abcd",
  "place": "xyz",
  "registrationid": 100
}];

var result = [];

userData.forEach((element) => {
  if (element.id != "" && element.registrationid == "") {
    console.log("1");
    result.push(element);
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id == "") {
    console.log("2");
    element.id = element.registrationid;
    result.push(element);
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id != "") {
    console.log("3");
    if (element.id == element.registrationid) {
      console.log("4");
      result.push(element);
    } else if (element.id != element.registrationid) {
      console.log("5");
      result.push({
        ...element
      })
      element.id = element.registrationid;
      result.push(element)
    }
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

The assignment in 3a doesn't make sense. I removed it. I prefer `flatMap`

```js
var userData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "abcd",
  "place": "xyz",
  "registrationid": 100
}];

var result = userData.flatMap((element) => {
  if (element.id != "" && element.registrationid == "") {
    console.log("1");
    return element;
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id == "") {
    console.log("2");
    element.id = element.registrationid;
    return element;
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id != "") {
    console.log("3");
    if (element.id == element.registrationid) {
      console.log("4");
      return element;
    } else if (element.id != element.registrationid) {
      console.log("5");
      const oldId = element.id;
      element.id = element.registrationid;
      return [{
        ...element, id: oldId
      }, element];
    }
  }
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```js
  const userData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abcd",
    "place": "xyz",
    "registrationid": 100
  }];
  const result = [];

  userData.forEach((data) => {
    if (data.id && !data.registrationid) {
      result.push(data);
    }

    if (!data.id && data.registrationid) {
      const output = {
        ...data,
        id: data.registrationid
      }

      result.push(output)
    }
    
    if (data.id && data.registrationid) {
      if (data.id === data.registrationid) {
        result.push(data);
      } else {
        const obj1 = {...data, id: 1};
        const obj2 = {...data, id: 100}
        
        result.push(obj1, obj2)
      }
    }
  });
  
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: This has a different behavior. It's unclear whether the modification of the original data is intentional, but you're changing the behavior. The code in the question modifies `userData`. Your code doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You could create new object if you wanna do this business

```
var userData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "abcd",
    place: "xyz",
    registrationid: 100,
  },
];

var result = [];

userData.forEach((element) => {
  let newEl;
  if (element.id != "" && element.registrationid == "") {
    newEl = { ...element };
    result.push(newEl);
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id == "") {
    newEl = { ...element, id: element.registrationid };
    result.push(newEl);
  } else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id != "") {
    result.push(element);
    if (element.id != element.registrationid) {
      newEl = { ...element, id: element.registrationid };
      result.push(newEl);
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This has a different behavior. It's unclear whether the modification of the original data is intentional, but you're changing the behavior. The code in the question modifies userData. Your code doesn't.

Comment: @jabaa i just double-check his question. he doesn't mention anything about he could modify his userData

Comment: The question contains a code that modifies `userData`. That should be enough. You don't need to mention it. It's not necessary to change this behavior. You can fix the problem and keep this behavior.

Comment: @jabaa and your code doesn't diff when compare with mine except i create a new variable that store his original data

Comment: But your code doesn't assign the ID in `userData`. That's a big difference. If the code in the question except part 3b is correct, your answer could break it.

Comment: in the 3b, he need 2 object with different `id` and nothing about modify `userData`. IMO you uncleared with his question

Comment: Yes, with 3b you're right. But 2 and 3a clearly say to modify the original object.

Comment: oh haha @jabaa you're right too :D. i missing the mention in 2 and 3a

Comment: @jabaa but the 3a i think that he doesn't need to assign the `regId` into `id` because the original data there are same type and same value

Answer (score 1):

```
var userData = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "abcd",
    "place": "xyz",
    "registrationid": 100
}];

var result = [];

userData.forEach((element) => {
if (element.id != "" && element.registrationid == "") {
    console.log("1");
    result.push(element);

} else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id == "") {
    console.log("2");
    element.id = element.registrationid;
    result.push(element);

} else if (element.registrationid != "" && element.id != "") {
    console.log("3");
    if (element.id == element.registrationid) {
        console.log("4");
        element.id = element.registrationid;
        result.push(element);

    } else if (element.id != element.registrationid) {
        console.log("5");
        result.push(element)
        // do not mutate data as below
        //element.id  = element.registrationid;
        // instead, create a new object and assign registrationid to id, like below
        result.push({ ...element, id: element.registrationid })
        result.push(element)
    }

}
});

console.log(result)
```

The problem was with mutation of the object. [Here](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/javascript-how-to-avoid-object-mutation-7cd733913a9f) is a good article about JS object mutation.

Comment: This has a different behavior. It's unclear whether the modification of the original data is intentional, but you're changing the behavior. The code in the question modifies userData. Your code doesn't. Maybe this mutation is required for the business logik

Comment: I don't think it has a different behavior from what is asked in the requirements. Even if it is for the business logic, all the user wants is a result with two objects, one with original `id` value and the other object with `id` assigned with `registrationid`, when `id` and `registrationid` are different, which cannot be achieved by mutating the object IMO.

Comment: After rereading the question, I think you're right. 3b shouldn't modify `userData`. But the code in the question contains a modification. It's unclear.

Comment: Right, the code in 3b in the question modifies the `userData`. However, that is the actual issue IMO which the author of the question made as it does not yield the intended result. Don't you think so?